# Reading data from csv by column and store in array list

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I have a data as below in .csv file.

```
| Name | Age | Place|
|Ram   | 20  | AP   |
|Srinu | 25  | TS   |
|Raju  | 22  | TN   |
```

How to read only Place from above csv file and store all values using list

Comment: Is the data saved on one line?
Or is the header on the first line, and the data rows separated by line breaks?
Not understanding how the data is saved in the `.csv` file

Comment: One row is stored in one line and follows the next like below
1.  Name|Age|Place|
2.  Ram|20|AP|
3.  Srinu|25|TS|

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Path/To/file.csv"));  
String line = "";  
String DELIMITER = "|";  
List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(DELIMITER);
        records.add(values[2]);
}
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv-file-array

Comment: Above code doesnot read only Place it reads all the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSVParser](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) class:

```
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator('|').build();

try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("/Path/To/file.csv"))
                           .withCSVParser(csvParser)   // custom CSV parser
                           .build()) {
    List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
} catch (IOException | CsvException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See more about using CSVParser [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)